# Python: Bytes to Floating Point

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, binaryfiles

I'm trying to parse a binary file that has a combination of 1,2,4,8 byte integers and 4,8 byte floating points as well as varying strings with different encodings.
How do I convert 4 bytes or 8 bytes to a floating point?

Is using the struct package the best way?
if so, how do I use the struct package to get a floating point? with 4-bytes and 8-bytes

How could i do the same thing with a 2-byte or 4-byte integer?
What i'm currently using is

```
int.from_bytes(binary_file.read(2), byteorder='little', signed=False)
int.from_bytes(binary_file.read(4), byteorder='little', signed=False)
```

Would it be more optimal to use struct for multiple ints and floats in succession?

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` module is by far the most obvious/correct way to do this. If you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) you'd find all the format codes you need in a few seconds.

`int.from_bytes` is more general (handles arbitrary widths), but when you know the precise widths, you're likely better off with a `struct`; if you do it a lot for the same formats, using a preconstructed `struct.Struct` object will run faster than the module-level functions.